# Creating PEM-format cert from N and e in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssl

I'm dealing with a web service that sends a public key down to the client in the following format.

```
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
```

Note the N and e values are separated by a colon ':'.

I would like to use OpenSSL::PKey::RSA in order to work with the public key, but it only accepts DER and PEM format certs. How can I format the public key I am given into a PEM or DER format cert that is consumable by the OpenSSL wrapper library in Ruby?

EDIT:

This python code does essentially what I am attempting to do in Ruby. I'm looking for the equivalent of the RSAPublicNumbers class.
https://github.com/jpf/okta-jwks-to-pem/blob/master/jwks_to_pem.py#L40

Comment: FWIW the end goal is simply encrypting a string.

Comment: Thank you for providing the Python link! That link was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Check `base64_to_long`

```
def generate_key_from_jwks(kid_header)
  key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new
  exponent = kid_header['e']
  modulus = kid_header['n']
  key.set_key(base64_to_long(modulus), base64_to_long(exponent), nil)
end

def base64_to_long(data)
  decoded_with_padding = Base64.urlsafe_decode64(data) + Base64.decode64('==')
  decoded_with_padding.to_s.unpack('C*').map do |byte|
    to_hex(byte)
  end.join.to_i(16)
end

def to_hex(int)
  int < 16 ? '0' + int.to_s(16) : int.to_s(16)
end
```